# Laravel exclude voted posts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have two tables: `posts` and `votes`, and I want to display only one post on home page, and then displaying them in random order. But I want to exclude posts that are already upvoted. So I want to loop only between not-voted posts. I am using Laravel 5.4

Structure for `posts` table:

- id
- user_id
- ...

Structure for `votes` table:

- id
- user_id
- post_id
- ...

I just need a query for excluding posts, everything else I already have written.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `votes` relationship in your `Post` model (I assume you use Eloquent) you can use:

```
$posts = Post::doesntHave('votes')->get();
```

to get posts that don't have any votes.

Obviously it might be not a good idea to run `get()` here as you will get all posts that don't have votes - and what in case there are 100 000 posts matching this criteria? You should probably only get some of them and then choose one random for example:

```
$posts = Post::doesntHave('votes')->latest()->take(100)->get();
```

Comment: Nice +1.But if votes does have upvote and downvote both and I only want to filter upvotes.

Comment: @LearnCss If you are using query builder you should use joins or nested queries to achieve the same. But it's more reasonable to use Eloquent in most of cases :)

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek yeah, but what if I want to order by the number of votes?

Comment: @LearnCss But you wrote "But I want to exclude posts that are already upvoted." so none of those posts will have any votes, so there's no point to order them by votes as all of them has 0 votes

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek yeah, but current user. But what if 5000 other users will upvote this post? I want to show most upvoted first

Comment: @LearnCss So you need probably one more query to get most upvoted posts. If you need it, you should probably ask another question for this